# Colour certain table cells created from javascript array

Tags: javascript, css, arrays

I am generating a table in javascript by looping through an array. I am trying to color the text of certain cells in which the number calculated is 10. Is there a way to call CSS within javascript? This is my current code being run thourgh html. Alternatively, is there a way to make CSS applied to styles using conditional statements?

```
<script>
var multitable;
numarray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
           
multitable = "<table>"
for (row = 1; row < 6; row++) {
   multitable += "<tr>"
   for (col = 0, i = 0; col < 5; col++, i++) {
       multitable += "<td >" + row + "x" + numarray[i] + " = " + row * numarray[i] + "</td>"                
   }
    multitable += "</tr>"
 }
 multitable += "</table>"
 document.write(multitable);

</script>
```

I was attempting to do something such as:

```
if (row*numarray[i] == 10)
    {
        // background colour green
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check that while creating the `td` and add a class to `td`

```js
var multitable;
numarray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

multitable = "<table>"
for (row = 1; row < 6; row++) {
  multitable += "<tr>"
  for (col = 0, i = 0; col < 5; col++, i++) {
    const sumVal = row * numarray[i];
    multitable += "<td class=" + (sumVal === 10 ? 'color' : '') + " >" + row + "x" + numarray[i] + " = " + sumVal + "</td>"
  }
  multitable += "</tr>"
}
multitable += "</table>"
document.write(multitable);
```

```css
.color {
  background: green;
}
```

Comment: Well this way the other `td's` will have **no** class names at all. Its **NOT** a good practice to add class without any names to them in DOM.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I answered the requirement. If the expectation was to have other `td` a different class then answer would have been different

Answer (score 2):

You were nearly there and on right track - You can check using `if` condition that total is `10` then can apply `class` to that `element`.

Also, its **not** a good practice to print everything using `document.write` you can use div `element` instead to show your `table`.

**Live Demo:**

```js
var multitable;
numarray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

multitable = "<table>"
for (row = 1; row < 6; row++) {
  multitable += "<tr>"
  for (col = 0, i = 0; col < 5; col++, i++) {
    if (row * numarray[i] == 10) {
      multitable += "<td class='red'>" + row + "x" + numarray[i] + " = " + row * numarray[i] + "</td>"
    } else {
      multitable += "<td >" + row + "x" + numarray[i] + " = " + row * numarray[i] + "</td>"
    }
  }
  multitable += "</tr>"
}
multitable += "</table>"

document.querySelector('#results').innerHTML = multitable;
```

```css
.red {
  background: red;
}

 table,
 table tr th,
 table tr td {
   border: 1px solid black;
 }
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the calculated number is 10 just add an css-class that highlights this row/cell.